# how i convert lists' elements x to this lists' elements y and how i get elements from nested list?

Tags: list-manipulation

i have nested list as follows

```
x = {{x11, x12, x13}, {x21, x22, x23}, {x31, x32, x33},{x41, x42, x43}} = {{1, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 3}, {2, 6, 7}, {2, 6, 8}}
```

i want to make x as follow and assign it to y

```
y = {{x11, x21, x31, x41}, {x12, x22, x32,x42}, {x13, x23, x33,x43}} = {{1, 3, 2, 2}, {3, 4, 6, 6}, {5, 3, 7, 8}}
```

another question
i have a list named z like this

```
z = {{34, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 2}}, {12, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 2}}, {12, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 1}}}
```

and i want to assign  `{{x1 -> 3, x2 -> 2}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 2}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 2}}` to w as follows

```
w= {{x1 -> 3, x2 -> 2}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 2}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 2}}
```

Comment: Does `y=Transpose[{{x11,x12,x13},{x21,x22,x23},{x31,x32,x33},{x41,x42,x43}}]` get you closer to what you want for the first question? I realize that doesn't make use of what you have already assigned to `x` but does the result of that give you some help? Or does `y=Transpose[x]` get you closer to what you want? Next look at `w=Map[Last,z]` for your second question

Comment: Second question. Should it be: {{x1 -> 3, x2 -> 2}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 2}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 1}}? This you can get by:  z[[All, 2]]